# Magento 1.8 admin account login shows white dashboard page

Tags: php, magento, admin

Without any change on system configuration and code since my last login, one day my admin account login shows blank dashboard page, header of the page is showed but most of content are blank. Big oddity is my customer service account is able to see her whole dashboard page and get her all backends working, however, as her account has system config part disabled, I can not do anything further. 
After clicking login, the URL has showed up: http://www.example.com/index.php/admin/dashboard/index/key/8062533e7ee0df2d1d693d1d70148ad8/

I check HTML rendering, header div of the page has rendered, it stopped at navigation div. the last rendering seen as below.

```
<div class="nav-bar">
<!-- menu start -->
```

Could any master help out please, I have no idea where to debug....Thank you so much...

Comment: well it doesn't magically disappear, have you tested your most recent backup to see if you can see the dashboard?

Comment: @cleong  Thank you for reply. there are two reasons I do not try backup.

Comment: First, I only keep 4 buckups weekly basis, but my last login to see dashboard page was more than a month ago. Second, since my customer service account is able to see her dashboard page, I suspect this might be result of shoplift bug that hacker did something after taking over admin login....BTW, I have done all patches, but I still got blank dashboard page.

Comment: might by right... should verify it though

Answer (score 0):

Try:

- clean all types of caches
- check permissions on folders(app/etc, var,
  media) should have 755 or higher.
- check logs(exeptions.log,
  system.log)
- enable errors reporting in
  index.php(ini_set('display_errors', 1);)

Comment: Thank you.  system log do have some  traces of hacker attacking (I assume). My permission was folder 755 and file 644. but it is found that hacker added some code in index.php, question is are those permission secure enough? I know nothing about hacking, but if I set permission on file 400 and folder 500 as per suggested by http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/install/installer-privileges_after.html. my web will be dead....anyone know the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for replying...It is confirmed due to shoplift bug. I applied all patches including latest 5994 patch, nothing changed...I turned on error display in index.php, indicated an error file from includes/src, so I asked hosting admin to turn off php compiler, then I got my admin login back to normal....
However, not sure if this is side effect of the bug, I can not see all images of all products from backend, they all gone. weird thing is all images are good to see from frontend...does anyone know how to do housekeeping after site was being attacked by hacker?